# Google Map on click of back button going to blank screen

Tags: android

I have implemented google map in my app. But the problem is whenever i click on back button it is going to blank page.
I referred few links but find it needful .
i have implemented the following code in java file but dint find it useful.

```
 public void onDestroy() {
       // gmap = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: It's just a callback of Activity Life Cycle, that gets called automatically when Activity is going to finish. For e.g. when user pressed back key. It's not going to work anything different till you implement anything inside it. Can you elaborate a little more about your issue or add your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the following in your activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Default behavior of the back press is finishing the activity. So I think there is no need of overriding onBackPress to simply calling finish().

Comment: but something is already overriding the default back press in his case so i had just given a tweak.